# the colums are not getting divided in grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">

          <div clas="col-sm-4">
              <div class="checks">
                  <span class="title">Appointment</span>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div clas="col-sm-8">
              <div class="doctor">
                  <span class="title">Dr Yogesh Sharma</span><br/>
                  Speciality: Heart, Brain, ENT<br/>
                  Experience: 11 years<br/>
                  Rating: <span>&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2605;&#x2606;</span> 4/5<br/>
                  Consultation fee:  &#x20b9;400 (In-clinic),&#x20b9;200 (Online)<br/>
                  <button class="btn btn-success" ">Show Clinic Details</button><br/>    
                  <details>
                      <summary>More Info... </summary>
                      Gender: Male
                      Education: MBBS      
                  </details>
                  <hr/>
              </div>  
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

I have declared `container-fluid` and `row` before trying to partiton but it doesnt work. It did the same thing above

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <form id="searchbox" action="">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select class="form-control" id="locality">
                    <option>Locality</option>
                    <option>Rohini</option>
                    <option>Noida</option>
                    <option>Gurugram</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select class="form-control" id="speciality">
                    <option>Speciality</option>
                    <option>Dentist</option>
                    <option>Physician</option>
                    <option>Surgeon</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control btn-primary btn" id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
            </div>
          </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this works

Comment: Very hard to work out what you want to achieve. A sample output will help. Having said that, in top snippet you have spelt 'class' incorrectly on lines 4 and 10, and that might be the error.

Comment: That's the error, totally my fault.